# Assign List<T> to IEnumerable<T> in static method

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` in a static method. Here is my code.

```
public class PlayController : Controller
{
    // GET: Play
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var a = new a();
        b.Test(a.ienuInt);

        return View();
    }
}

public class a
{
    public IEnumerable<int> ienuInt { get; set; }

    public a()
    {
        ienuInt = new List<int>();
    }
}

public class b
{
    public static void Test(IEnumerable<int> model)
    {
        var lists = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        model = lists;
    }
}
```

I expect that the `ienuInt` of `a` is assigned `lists` initialised in `static void Test` method. But after the `Test` method, the `ienuInt` does not have anything. Its count is `0` means that nothing is assigned to it.

Is there any problem? Cause I thought I could assign the `lists` to `ienuInt` because passing `ienuInt` as a parameter means passing reference not value.

Can you tell me how to handle this?

Comment: In that case, there are no reason why `b.Test` method would not returns `lists` and have no parameter.

Comment: Wouldn't `Test(ref IEnumerable<int> model)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you're witnessing is a kind of "passing by reference" vs. "passing by value".

When you pass your object to the `Test` method, the variable `model` inside that method is only a reference to the original object.  When you assign it to a new object in that method, you're just changing the reference.  This doesn't modify the original object.

To illustrate:

```
public static void Test(SomeObject model)
{
    // Only changes which object in memory "model" points to.
    // The original object outside of this method is unchanged.
    // There are now two objects in memory.
    model = new SomeObject();
}

public static void Test(SomeObject model)
{
    // There's still only one object in memory.
    // The object which was passed to this method sees the change.
    model.SomeProperty = someValue;
}
```

In your case what you can do is *return* this new object and set it to the variable outside of the method.  So have the method return the new object:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Test()
{
    return new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

And then the calling code would handle updating its variable:

```
var a = new a();
a.ienuInt = b.Test();
```

**Or** you could pass the entire instance of `a` and update the property on that object.  Something like this:

```
public static void Test(a model)
{
    var lists = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    model.ienuInt = lists;
}
```

And then pass that whole model to the method:

```
var a = new a();
b.Test(a);
```

In this case there would still only be one instance of `a` since a new one isn't created in the method.  The method is just modifying a property on `a`.

---

(Side note: Naming your classes and variables the same thing is just asking for confusion.  Stick with naming conventions.  For example, call the class `A` and the variable `a`.)

Comment: so the "model" is stored on "stack" memory and it saves reference to IEnumerable<int> stored in Heap memory. So when I assign the new object to it, I only changes the reference of "model" on "stack" memory. is it right?

Comment: @kisungTae: The variable `model` is just in that method (stack frame), yes.  And it's just a pointer to the object in the heap.  So when you assign the variable, you just change the pointer.  But when you modify a property on the variable, you follow the pointer to the object and modify the object.

Comment: Oh Thanks for the quick response

Comment: You cannot return a value from a `void` method as your `Test` method attempts to do.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Good catch, thanks!  Should be fixed now.